# 64 bit application starting 32 bit process

Tags: c#, process, 32bit-64bit, bit

I'm working on a 64 bit application coded with .Net 4.0, C#.

In this application, at some point, I need to start another *exe* file using the following code:

```
l_process.StartInfo.FileName = _sFullFilePath;
l_process.StartInfo.Verb = "Open";
l_process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
l_process.StartInfo.Arguments = l_sParams;

l_process.Start();
```

Now, this external application being compiled under 32 bit environment (x86), I get the following error:

> The specified executable is not valid for this OS platform

Is it even possible to do so ? If yes, how can I manage to start this application from mine without having troubles?

Comment: I start processes like that all the time - so, it works. Check your setup - can be the 32 bit app is not really 32 bit (started as 54 bit, linking to a 32 bit library).

Comment: Does external application even execute on this environment?

Comment: @TomTom - What the heck is a 54 bit application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, no extra work is required to run a 32-bit program on 64-bit machine.

1. Try to run 32-bit program individually.
2. Read this: https://web.archive.org/web/20120103081542/http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/how-windows7-vista64-support-32bit-applications.htm

Comment: 1. Running it individually is working!
2. Is there something I need to do in my code to tell my application it's a 32 bits exe !

Comment: No change in code should be required. Check using `depends` if any dll is missing OR 32-bit app. is trying to link a 64-bit dll, required by 64-bit app also.